# Write / Read LSO Flash Cookie in ASP .Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a Device fingerprinting application where I need to write LSO flash cookie on client PC. Can someone help me to write /read LSO Flash Cookie in ASP .Net C#?

Answer (score 0):

By default, ASP.NET uses HttpCookies. LSO (A.K.A. Flash cookies) are a different kind of cookies that most likely would be stored in a different client folder (are not cleaned when browser deletes cookies) and would have a diferent format.

```
%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects
```

I dont think that with client scripting that path would be accesible.

Perhaps creating a flash swf that would read other SWF's files, but I doubt macromedia would allow that.

I would suggest going to OWASP and checking your options/tools regarding Flash https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Flash_Security_Project